# How to selected the item from the search bar in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, searchbar

I'm trying to get the string value of a selected item from the search bar. If to select Apple, then to get as string the value "Apple".

[image]

I have tried to use *SearchButtonPressed* but is not working at all. This is my code for the search bar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="Sim.Views.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    Title="Main Page">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid BackgroundColor="DarkGray">
            <StackLayout Margin="10"
                         VerticalOptions="Start"
                         HorizontalOptions="Start">
                <SearchBar x:Name="searchBar"
                   HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                   VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                   Placeholder="Search Access Points..."
                   CancelButtonColor="Orange"
                   PlaceholderColor="Orange"
                   TextTransform="Lowercase"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                   TextChanged="OnTextChanged"
                           />
                
                <Label Text="Type in the searchbox."
               HorizontalOptions="Fill"
               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                <ListView x:Name="searchResults"
                  HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                          IsVisible="False"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/searchbar  That has an example with a ViewModel with property "SearchResults".  That property gets set whenever user makes a selection.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Do you want the value the user enters in the search bar, or do you want the value the user selects from the list?  "tried to use SearchButtonPressed but is not working at all" - where is this code that you tried for this?

Comment: @Jason in the description I said "value of a selected item from the search bar".

Comment: You could filter your data in your `OnTextChanged` event,and set the new data to your listview.

Comment: I've done that. But it works when 'The text is changed'. But I try to get the text of the item that was clicked from this search result list.

Comment: If you want the text of the item that was "Clicked" then use the ItemSelected or ItemTapped events of the ListView.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by adding *ItemTapped*

```
<ListView x:Name="searchResults"
          HorizontalOptions="Fill"
          VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
          ItemTapped ="GetTappedItem"/>

void GetTappedItem(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    var details = e.Item;
}
```

Thank you @Jason.